# Writing a character who has panic attacks

Tags: creative-writing

I myself do not have panic attacks, but I do know a few people who have had them. A few even while I'm around-- so I know what I'm doing for the most part, but..

There is a certain scene in the story where said character is having a panic attack after he is left alone (he is a prince and his guards, who at least one of them is with him 24-7, all go off somewhere and he has no idea where they are)

After it occurs to him that none of them are with him, he begins to have a panic attack, and this happens during an invasion on his kingdom where monsters are attacking.

During his panic attack, he is about to be attacked by a monster before one of his guards comes back to save him. His guard ends up becoming extremely injured, possibly near death.

My problem figuring out this scene is questioning whether his guard showing up and nearly dying would snap him back to reality, or if he would fall into even more of a panic and would be unable to help the guard. Or is this something where it would depend? How do I decide between these two alternatives?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. This is a "what to write" question, which is off-topic for us. You might have some luck if you do some research into the physiology and psychology of panic attacks (what causes them, what happens to the body and brain, how long they last, what the physical and lasting psychological effects are), and/or try to find first-person accounts. Direct research is going to serve you best, I think.

Comment: I think this will be quite difficult to find out from literature research alone. Psychology studies the causes of panic attacks and the possible treatments. It does not study what happens to a person who has a panik attack and is then faced with actual danger. You might have to ask an expert. What I would do is find a clincial psychologist whose research interest is panic attacks, and then write a polite email to that person, briefly explain why you are interested, and then ask what would happen. If you can do all this in about three sentences, you will very likely receive a reply.

Comment: I modified the question by asking how to decide between the two alternatives. That "question" actually has some answers below.

Comment: The question would be on topic over at cogsci.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It's your story. Just write it.

Answer (score 2):

I've had panic attacks. The most revealing event that happened to me during my panic attack years was when I admitted myself into an SLC hospital after having an episode. I was hyper-ventilating, my fingers and toes were numb and I thought I was dying. When I surrendered myself at the hospital, an angelic triage nurse told me - the worst thing that can happen to you right now is that your body will do its job and make you pass out. Your body "knows" what to do in this situation and that is to shut down. The angelic nurse told me that she'd admit me into the hospital - but didn't want to. She preferred for me to recognize my bodily functions and to just go home. I did. I left the hospital with a grandiose understanding of myself; however, I did not conquer the panic attics until years later. I continued to have trouble going to sleep thinking that my heart would stop if I succumbed to sleep. One night I said to myself - fuck it!!! If I am going to die - let's do it! But it would have to be while standing in front of my fears. Facing my warped fears worked perfectly! I told myself - ok - let's die - but only in the position of facing my fears straight up - not while retreating. The panic attacks never entered into my life again.

Comment: Inspiring story!  Now, do you happen to have an answer for the OP?  (I don't mind that you didn't really answer the question.  My son has OCD and I found your paragraph fascinating.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and thank you for being brave enough to share it). I think this is the kind of first-person experience the OP needs, although this board is not the place to gather such accounts.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum: Even from a "fiction" point of view, this is a possible resolution, and therefore helpful to the question, IMHO.

Comment: @TomAu The question is certainly answerable and this answer is useful. But Writers doesn't take questions about "Help me figure out what to do with my specific scene/plot point." That's classified as a *what to write* question. It's brainstorming or workshopping. Not on-topic for us. "How do I write about a condition I've never experienced?" would be on-topic.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum: And I edited/changed the question to "how do I choose between [two] alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Either one is plausible.  Work backwards from where your plot needs to get to.

Comment: I agree with aparente001 here. Either you research what would happen in real life and write your story accordingly. Or, if you cannot find that information or do not care about realism, write it according to the direction you want your plot to take.